# Where to place adapter.notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview, baseadapter and data from SQLite, including a BLOB. What if the SQL-query changes? (After pressing a button to execute a new SQL-query) I have to use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged

Where can I place that line of code?

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.example);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    placeData = new DatabaseSQL(this);

    String cmd = "select * from plaatjes ";

    Cursor cursors = getRawEvents(cmd);

    if (cursors.moveToNext()) {
        getDataAndPopulate(cmd);
    }

}

private void getDataAndPopulate(String cmd) {
    id = new ArrayList<String>();
    image = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
    caption = new ArrayList<String>();
    description = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor = getRawEvents(cmd); 
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String temp_id = cursor.getString(0);
        byte[] temp_image = cursor.getBlob(1);
        String temp_caption = cursor.getString(2);
        String temp_description = cursor.getString(3);
        id.add(temp_id);
        image.add(temp_image);
        caption.add(temp_caption);
        description.add(temp_description);
    }
    String[] captionArray = (String[]) caption.toArray(
            new String[caption.size()]);

    ItemsAdapter itemsAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(
            Example.this, R.layout.item,
            captionArray);

    setListAdapter(itemsAdapter);

}


private class ItemsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    String[] items;

    public ItemsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int POSITION, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView desc;
        TextView cap;
        View view = convertView;
        ImageView img;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

        } 
        img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        cap = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.caption);
        desc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);

        cap.setText(caption.get(POSITION));
        desc.setText(description.get(POSITION));
        img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image.get(POSITION), 0, image.get(POSITION).length));


        return view;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return items.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}

private Cursor getRawEvents(String sql) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = (placeData).getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    return cursor;
}

private Cursor getEvents(String table) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = (placeData).getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(table, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    return cursor;
}
```

}

Comment: use it in a button's *onClickListener* event

Comment: In first line of your getDataAndPopulate(String cmd) method

Comment: At that point it doesn't know itemsAdapter yet. I've tried it just one line above setListAdapter(itemsAdapter) and one line below, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all where is the ListView?
Secondly, don't put the adapter in the getDataAndPopulate() function. Why are you generating a new adapter everytime?

Here is the order in which to put them,

1. ListView
2. Cursor
3. Fill the data array [call a function that does it. getDataAndPopulate() ]
4. Set the data array to the adapter. Make the adapter global in the Activity class file.
5. Set the adapter to the list.

In your onClick of the Button
1. execute the query and fill up the data array.
2. call adapter.notifyDatasetChanged().

You ought to use a Cursor Adapter. Would make your life way simpler ;)

Comment: Do u mean it is not required at all? or not in the onClick call?

Comment: yes, it is not required in this case because the adapter keeps unchanged after being set to listview. if content of the adapter change and you also want to update the list, there you should call notifyDatasetChanged(). it is just for updating the list, not for first time.

Comment: Exactly. That is why i mentioned that the notifydatasetchanged should be in the onclick of the button. I think its not that evident. Let me restructure it.

Comment: welcome :) if it works for u then u could select it as the right answer and upvote it ;)

Comment: I did exactly what you told me to do. The only problem is that notifyDataSetChanged() doesn't refresh the listview so if if a new list has fewer items then the initial one it crashes when I scroll down. I looks for values in the arraylist wich aren't there anymore. The new array is OK, the new arraylists are OK, but notifyDataSetChanged doesn't refresh the listview itself.

Comment: i went over & i missed out on an important point. sorry about that. I see u r extending from an Base adapter. I suggest you try extending from an array adapter as u r passing an array. You see the problem that is happening here is, u are refreshing ure captionarray with the new data but when u call a notifydatasetchange() the new array in your adapter is not really getting updated. In an arrayadapter that would happen. Incase you are getting confused, I had written a tutorial sometime back. might make things clear.
http://www.shubhayu.com/android/listview-with-arrayadapter-and-customized-items

Comment: My adapter now extends an ArrayAdapter and finally it works perfect. Thank you SO MUCH! BUT: itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() does NOT work! I use these 2 lines: itemsAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(Agenda.this)

Comment: Sorry. 2 lines: 1. itemsAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(Agenda.this) 2. deLijst.setAdapter(itemsAdapter) each time the list is refreshed and that makes it happen.

Comment: that is indeed weird. I'll look into it soon. But I am glad you got it working finally :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `notifyDatasetChanged()`, because you fill the adapter and set it to `ListView` once. calling `notifyDatasetChanged()` is needed when you change the content of the adapter **after** setting it to a `ListView`, and you want to update the list.

Comment: But after the query changes ("select * from plaatjes where id = 1") the program crashes. How can I solve that problem?

Comment: post DDMS log please, there might be an error related to database.